# Jekyll Pagination for multiple pages

Tags: pagination, jekyll, jekyll-paginator

So right now I have the following in my **config.yml**:

```
gems: [jekyll-paginate]
paginate: 3
paginate_path: "page:num"
```

So in my **index.html** page I have the following:

```
{% for post in paginator.posts %}
Stuff
{% endfor %}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how I would make separate category pages and have pagination for them.

Could anyone help me shed light? I've been googling forever and I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll only manages posts pagination.

If you want to paginate categories, you will need a plugin like https://github.com/midnightSuyama/jekyll-paginate-category.

Comment: They give you no directions here so it's quite complicated.